# Android Kotlin : Search for element with specific key value in mutableList

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelist

I have a mutableList of Cars (Cars is a data class).
I'm searching a way to find the Car with a specific id in my mutable list. 
How can i achieve that in Kotlin?

**Car.kt**

```
data class Car(
    val createdAt: String = "",
    val updatedAt: String = "",
    val id: String = "",
    val number: String = ""
)
```

In my **CarsFragment.kt**:

```
var cars: MutableList<Car>

// extract Car with id = "89Ddzedzedze8998" ?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **firstOrNull** or **find** to get the result or **null** in case no car available with the given id.

```
fun getCarById(carId: Int) {
   val myCar: Car? = carsList.firstOrNull { it.id == carId }
    // or

   val myCar: Car? = carsList.find { it.id == carId }
}
```

Now you can easily check if you get actual value or null, and move further accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

So you want something like that

```
val idToCheck = "89Ddzedzedze8998"
cars.first {car->
  car.id == idToCheck
}
```

**update**

as mention by [a_local_nobody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4729721/a-local-nobody) it is worth mentioning that [first](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first.html) will throw an `NoSuchElementException` but [firstOrNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-or-null.html) will return `null`

Comment: nice answer, but it's worth adding that `first` will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if no item is found, that's why I personally prefer `firstOrNull` :)

Comment: yes it will throw an exception, but in the question he/she don't mention how to handle the item. Maybe he/she prefer exception instead of null, it is totally up to you to use whatever your prefer.

Comment: yeah i agree the question has no further info, it was just worth adding for anyone reading

Answer (score 3):

You can do using find in kotlin

```
val idToCheck = "89Ddzedzedze8998"
 cars.find { it.id == idToCheck  }
```